# Styling custom component in react native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add styling to my custom component in react native, but no matter what I do, the style has no effect. Here is my code:

```js
// App.js
import MyCustomComponent from './components/myCustomComponent.js';

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MyCustomComponent style={{marginTop: 10}}/>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The project compiles fine, and my custom component appears on screen fine, but the marginTop styling is not applied. It is worth noting that the style for the parent `View` component does apply correctly. This is a brand new project I just created today. This seems like it should be extremely basic, but just isn't working. What can I do to apply this styling?

Custom component code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, View, Button} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class MyCustomComponent extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={{ uri: "source here" }}
          style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
         />
         <TextInput
          style={{ height: 50 }}
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show me code of custom component?

Comment: style your `MyCustomComponent` to  `container` view

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
export default class MyCustomComponent extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container, {...this.props.style}]}>
        ...
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

now, `styles.container` is applied and anything you pass to component through `style` will be added to component style.

I hope this can help you

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a style to your custom component by passing style as props.

and

Use it as **style={this.props.style}** in your MyCustomComponent.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput, StyleSheet, Image, View, Button} from 'react-native';

type Props = {};
export default class MyCustomComponent extends Component<Props> {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.container,{...this.props.style}]}>//<--Use like this---
        <Image
          source={{ uri: "source here" }}
          style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
         />
         <TextInput
          style={{ height: 50 }}
          placeholder="Search"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your `CustomText.js` file (custom component):

```
import React from 'react'
import {Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

const CustomText = props => {
    return (<Text {...props} style={{...styles.text, ...props.style}}>{props.children}</Text>);
}

export default CustomText;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text:{
        color: '#000'
    }
})
```

and use in the file:

```
<CustomText style={styles.text}>My text</CustomText>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    text:{
        fontSize: 20,
    }
});
```

this code `merge` styles and pass all property to the custom components.

Answer (score 0):

For example, lets change background color of custom card.
Custom Card:

```
export default function MyCard({color}) {
    return (
         <View style={[styles.card, {backgroundColor: color}]}>
        </View>
    )
}
```

In another file

```
<MyCard color={"pink"} />
```

Here, styles.card is the style added in Custom Card file and the color is given during component use.
Note: MyCard(**{**color**}**) if you miss to add highlight parentheses, it will not work. I faced this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply this style yourself inside `MyCystomComponent`. For example:

```
const MyCustomComponent = ({style}) => (
  <View style={style}> // This will be the style that is passed as a prop.
  </View>
);
```